# Fedora 35 - intermittent wifi inaccessibility [wifi adapter not found]

Tags: linux, fedora, iwlwifi

I recently installed Fedora 35 (kernel 5.16) alongside Windows 10. Wifi adapter is Intel 8265.

When I boot up Fedora, sometimes the wireless options are completely gone and with `dmesg | grep iwl` I get:

```
iwlwifi: probe of 0000:06:00.0 failed with error -110
```

I installed the firmware but to no avail.

Already tried:

- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=264077
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259387/wifi-adapter-not-found-ubuntu-20-04-dmesg-grep-iwl-fails-to-wake-nic
- https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/iwlwifi-firmware-missing-in-linux-firmware/16516
- https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/fedora-33-does-not-recognise-wifi-of-laptop/11399/6

Comment: Try 5.17.2, see if it works. If it doesn't file a bug report at bugzilla.kernel.org/

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov It did not work. However, I've noticed that this problem occurs only when I switch from windows to fedora.

Comment: Maybe it is similar problem: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1918191#p1918191

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no direct fix, altough I managed to find 2 workarounds:

1. Disable Windows fast boot . Some people [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205299) found it helpful.
2. Enter Airplane Mode in Windows before switching systems. This avoids ['race condition'](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=264077).

Comment: Again, this is a bug in the kernel/drivers and it must be fixed. Not filing it means other users will suffer.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I have already submitted the bug :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. Connect your Fedora system to wifi via any smartphone USB tethering for internet connectivity.
2. Use the command `sudo dnf install '*-firmware'`.

In my case, at first, Fedora started disconnecting wifi periodically then the wifi adapter disappeared.